# Tables are not merged in the table. Normal tables are well merged. I wonder what the cause is

Tags: java, apache-poi

Correct image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlsV4.png)

[image]

Tables are not merged in the table.

Normal tables are well merged.

I wonder what the cause is.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();

        // create main table
        XWPFTable table = doc.createTable();

        // create rows and cells
        XWPFTableRow row = table.getRow(0);
        row.getCell(0).setText("Main table A1");
        row.addNewTableCell().setText("Main table B1");
        row.addNewTableCell().setText("Main table C1");

        row = table.createRow();
        row.setHeight(2000);
        row.getCell(0).setText("Main table A2");
        row.getCell(1).setText("Main table B2");
        row.getCell(2).setText("Main table C2");

        row = table.createRow();
        row.setHeight(2000);
        row.getCell(0).setText("Main table d2");
        row.getCell(1).setText("Main table d2");
        row.getCell(2).setText("Main table d2");

        // 1
        row = table.getRow(0);
        XWPFTableCell cell = row.getTableCells().get(0);
        XWPFParagraph paragraph = cell.addParagraph();

        // 2
        org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor cursor = paragraph.getCTP().newCursor();

        XWPFTable innerTable = cell.insertNewTbl(cursor);

        // 3
        innerTable.setTopBorder(XWPFTable.XWPFBorderType.SINGLE, 4, 0, "000000");
        innerTable.setRightBorder(XWPFTable.XWPFBorderType.SINGLE, 4, 0, "000000");
        innerTable.setBottomBorder(XWPFTable.XWPFBorderType.SINGLE, 4, 0, "000000");
        innerTable.setLeftBorder(XWPFTable.XWPFBorderType.SINGLE, 4, 0, "000000");
        innerTable.setInsideHBorder(XWPFTable.XWPFBorderType.SINGLE, 4, 0, "000000");
        innerTable.setInsideVBorder(XWPFTable.XWPFBorderType.SINGLE, 4, 0, "000000");

        // 4
        XWPFTableRow rowInInnerTable = innerTable.createRow();
        rowInInnerTable.setHeight(1000);

        XWPFTableCell cellInInnerTable = rowInInnerTable.createCell();
        cellInInnerTable.setColor("FF00FF");
        rowInInnerTable.getCell(0).setWidth("700");
        rowInInnerTable.getCell(0).setVerticalAlignment(XWPFVertAlign.CENTER);
        XWPFParagraph p5 = rowInInnerTable.getCell(0).getParagraphs().get(0);

        p5.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
        XWPFRun r5 = p5.createRun();
        r5.setFontSize(10);
        r5.setText("SUB_TAB1");

        cellInInnerTable = rowInInnerTable.createCell();
        rowInInnerTable.getCell(1).setWidth("300"); // ??? ??
        rowInInnerTable.getCell(1).setVerticalAlignment(XWPFVertAlign.CENTER);
        cellInInnerTable.setColor("FF00FF"); // ??
        p5 = rowInInnerTable.getCell(1).getParagraphs().get(0);
        p5.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
        r5 = p5.createRun();
        r5.setFontSize(10);
        r5.setText("SUB_TAB3");

        cellInInnerTable = rowInInnerTable.createCell();
        cellInInnerTable.setColor("FF00FF"); // ??
        rowInInnerTable.getCell(2).setWidth("2000"); // ??? ??
        rowInInnerTable.getCell(2).setVerticalAlignment(XWPFVertAlign.CENTER);
        p5 = rowInInnerTable.getCell(2).getParagraphs().get(0);
        p5.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
        r5 = p5.createRun();
        r5.setText("SUB_TAB4");

        rowInInnerTable = innerTable.createRow();
        cellInInnerTable = rowInInnerTable.getCell(0);
        p5 = rowInInnerTable.getCell(0).getParagraphs().get(0);
        p5.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
        r5 = p5.createRun();
        r5.setText("AA");

        cellInInnerTable = rowInInnerTable.getCell(1);
        p5 = rowInInnerTable.getCell(1).getParagraphs().get(0);
        p5.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
        r5 = p5.createRun();
        r5.setText("BB1");

        cellInInnerTable = rowInInnerTable.getCell(2);
        p5 = rowInInnerTable.getCell(2).getParagraphs().get(0);
        p5.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
        r5 = p5.createRun();
        r5.setText("CC");

        rowInInnerTable = innerTable.createRow();
        cellInInnerTable = rowInInnerTable.getCell(0);
        p5 = rowInInnerTable.getCell(0).getParagraphs().get(0);
        p5.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
        r5 = p5.createRun();
        r5.setText("AA_2");

        setColumnWidth(table, 0, 0, 4500);
        setColumnWidth(table, 0, 1, 2000);
        setColumnWidth(table, 0, 2, 2000);

        mergeCellVertically(table, 1, 1, 2);
        mergeCellVertically(innerTable, 1, 1, 2); // ????????????????????????????

        // save to .docx file
        try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("c:\\test\\MAIN_table.docx")) {
            doc.write(out);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void setColumnWidth(XWPFTable table, int row, int col, int width) {
    CTTblWidth tblWidth = CTTblWidth.Factory.newInstance();
    tblWidth.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(width));
    tblWidth.setType(STTblWidth.DXA);
    CTTcPr tcPr = table.getRow(row).getCell(col).getCTTc().getTcPr();
    if (tcPr != null) {
        tcPr.setTcW(tblWidth);
    } else {
        tcPr = CTTcPr.Factory.newInstance();
        tcPr.setTcW(tblWidth);
        table.getRow(row).getCell(col).getCTTc().setTcPr(tcPr);
    }
}

static void mergeCellVertically(XWPFTable table, int col, int fromRow, int toRow) {
    for (int rowIndex = fromRow; rowIndex <= toRow; rowIndex++) {
        XWPFTableCell cell = table.getRow(rowIndex).getCell(col);
        CTVMerge vmerge = CTVMerge.Factory.newInstance();
        if (rowIndex == fromRow) {
            vmerge.setVal(STMerge.RESTART);
        } else {
            vmerge.setVal(STMerge.CONTINUE);
            for (int i = cell.getParagraphs().size(); i > 0; i--) {
                cell.removeParagraph(0);
            }
            cell.addParagraph();
        }
        CTTcPr tcPr = cell.getCTTc().getTcPr();
        if (tcPr == null) {
            tcPr = cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr();
        }
        tcPr.setVMerge(vmerge);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and format your code properly.

Comment: um, pardon me but i don't quite catch which part should be merged and which part shouldn't. is the picture shows the expected result or the problem?

Comment: The second and third must merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if [XWPFTable.createRow](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTable.html#createRow--) messes the table's row array, at least for tables in tables. My debugging had shown that `XWPFTable.getRow(0)` gets the second row when `XWPFTable` is a table in a table and the row was added using `XWPFTable.createRow`. `XWPFTable.getRow(1)` gets the third row then and the first row is not reachable using `XWPFTable.getRow`.

If [XWPFTable.insertNewTableRow](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTable.html#insertNewTableRow-int-) is used to add the rows, then `XWPFTable.getRow` works correctly.

Complete example:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*;

public class CreateWordTableInTable2 {
    
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();

        // create main table
        XWPFTable table = doc.createTable();

        // create rows and cells
        XWPFTableRow row = table.getRow(0);
        row.getCell(0).setText("Main table A1");
        row.addNewTableCell().setText("Main table B1");
        row.addNewTableCell().setText("Main table C1");

        row = table.createRow();
        row.setHeight(2000);
        row.getCell(0).setText("Main table A2");
        row.getCell(1).setText("Main table B2");
        row.getCell(2).setText("Main table C2");

        row = table.createRow();
        row.setHeight(2000);
        row.getCell(0).setText("Main table d2");
        row.getCell(1).setText("Main table d2");
        row.getCell(2).setText("Main table d2");

        // 1
        row = table.getRow(0);
        XWPFTableCell cell = row.getTableCells().get(0);
        XWPFParagraph paragraph = cell.addParagraph();

        // 2
        org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor cursor = paragraph.getCTP().newCursor();

        XWPFTable innerTable = cell.insertNewTbl(cursor);

        // 3
        innerTable.setTopBorder(XWPFTable.XWPFBorderType.SINGLE, 4, 0, "000000");
        innerTable.setRightBorder(XWPFTable.XWPFBorderType.SINGLE, 4, 0, "000000");
        innerTable.setBottomBorder(XWPFTable.XWPFBorderType.SINGLE, 4, 0, "000000");
        innerTable.setLeftBorder(XWPFTable.XWPFBorderType.SINGLE, 4, 0, "000000");
        innerTable.setInsideHBorder(XWPFTable.XWPFBorderType.SINGLE, 4, 0, "000000");
        innerTable.setInsideVBorder(XWPFTable.XWPFBorderType.SINGLE, 4, 0, "000000");

        // 4
        //XWPFTableRow rowInInnerTable = innerTable.createRow();
        XWPFTableRow rowInInnerTable = innerTable.insertNewTableRow(0);
        rowInInnerTable.setHeight(1000);

        XWPFTableCell cellInInnerTable = rowInInnerTable.createCell();
        cellInInnerTable.setColor("FF00FF");
        rowInInnerTable.getCell(0).setWidth("700");
        rowInInnerTable.getCell(0).setVerticalAlignment(XWPFTableCell.XWPFVertAlign.CENTER);
        XWPFParagraph p5 = rowInInnerTable.getCell(0).getParagraphs().get(0);

        p5.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
        XWPFRun r5 = p5.createRun();
        r5.setFontSize(10);
        r5.setText("SUB_TAB1");

        cellInInnerTable = rowInInnerTable.createCell();
        rowInInnerTable.getCell(1).setWidth("300"); // ??? ??
        rowInInnerTable.getCell(1).setVerticalAlignment(XWPFTableCell.XWPFVertAlign.CENTER);
        cellInInnerTable.setColor("FF00FF"); // ??
        p5 = rowInInnerTable.getCell(1).getParagraphs().get(0);
        p5.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
        r5 = p5.createRun();
        r5.setFontSize(10);
        r5.setText("SUB_TAB3");

        cellInInnerTable = rowInInnerTable.createCell();
        cellInInnerTable.setColor("FF00FF"); // ??
        rowInInnerTable.getCell(2).setWidth("2000"); // ??? ??
        rowInInnerTable.getCell(2).setVerticalAlignment(XWPFTableCell.XWPFVertAlign.CENTER);
        p5 = rowInInnerTable.getCell(2).getParagraphs().get(0);
        p5.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
        r5 = p5.createRun();
        r5.setText("SUB_TAB4");

        //rowInInnerTable = innerTable.createRow();
        //cellInInnerTable = rowInInnerTable.getCell(0);
        rowInInnerTable = innerTable.insertNewTableRow(1);
        cellInInnerTable = rowInInnerTable.createCell();
        p5 = rowInInnerTable.getCell(0).getParagraphs().get(0);
        p5.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
        r5 = p5.createRun();
        r5.setText("AA");

        //cellInInnerTable = rowInInnerTable.getCell(1);
        cellInInnerTable = rowInInnerTable.createCell();
        p5 = rowInInnerTable.getCell(1).getParagraphs().get(0);
        p5.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
        r5 = p5.createRun();
        r5.setText("BB1");

        //cellInInnerTable = rowInInnerTable.getCell(2);
        cellInInnerTable = rowInInnerTable.createCell();
        p5 = rowInInnerTable.getCell(2).getParagraphs().get(0);
        p5.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
        r5 = p5.createRun();
        r5.setText("CC");

        //rowInInnerTable = innerTable.createRow();
        //cellInInnerTable = rowInInnerTable.getCell(0);
        rowInInnerTable = innerTable.insertNewTableRow(2);
        cellInInnerTable = rowInInnerTable.createCell();
        p5 = rowInInnerTable.getCell(0).getParagraphs().get(0);
        p5.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
        r5 = p5.createRun();
        r5.setText("AA_2");
        
        //cellInInnerTable = rowInInnerTable.getCell(1);
        cellInInnerTable = rowInInnerTable.createCell();

        //cellInInnerTable = rowInInnerTable.getCell(2);
        cellInInnerTable = rowInInnerTable.createCell();

        setColumnWidth(table, 0, 0, 4500);
        setColumnWidth(table, 0, 1, 2000);
        setColumnWidth(table, 0, 2, 2000);

        mergeCellVertically(table, 1, 1, 2);
        mergeCellVertically(innerTable, 1, 1, 2); // ????????????????????????????

        // save to .docx file
        try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./MAIN_table.docx")) {
            doc.write(out);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void setColumnWidth(XWPFTable table, int row, int col, int width) {
    CTTblWidth tblWidth = CTTblWidth.Factory.newInstance();
    tblWidth.setW(java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(width));
    tblWidth.setType(STTblWidth.DXA);
    CTTcPr tcPr = table.getRow(row).getCell(col).getCTTc().getTcPr();
    if (tcPr != null) {
        tcPr.setTcW(tblWidth);
    } else {
        tcPr = CTTcPr.Factory.newInstance();
        tcPr.setTcW(tblWidth);
        table.getRow(row).getCell(col).getCTTc().setTcPr(tcPr);
    }
}

static void mergeCellVertically(XWPFTable table, int col, int fromRow, int toRow) {
    for (int rowIndex = fromRow; rowIndex <= toRow; rowIndex++) {
        XWPFTableCell cell = table.getRow(rowIndex).getCell(col);
        //System.out.println(cell.getTableRow().getCtRow()); // wrong row in inner table when XWPFTable.createRow was used
        CTVMerge vmerge = CTVMerge.Factory.newInstance();
        if (rowIndex == fromRow) {
            vmerge.setVal(STMerge.RESTART);
        } else {
            vmerge.setVal(STMerge.CONTINUE);
            for (int i = cell.getParagraphs().size(); i > 0; i--) {
                cell.removeParagraph(0);
            }
            cell.addParagraph();
        }
        CTTcPr tcPr = cell.getCTTc().getTcPr();
        if (tcPr == null) {
            tcPr = cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr();
        }
        tcPr.setVMerge(vmerge);
    }
}

}
```

Result:

[image]

If it comes to the question why this happens, then my suspicion is that [XWPFTable.addColumn](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_5_2_3/poi-ooxml/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTable.java?view=markup#l426) is the guilty. This is the main differnce between `XWPFTable.createRow` and `XWPFTable.insertNewTableRow`. The first tries filling the new added row with as much cells as columns are in the table already. The second does not and adds an empty row.

Me never understood that behavior of `XWPFTable.createRow`. Why should it be necessary to fill the new added row with as much cells as columns are in the table already? Why not simply let the programmer add cells to the row?

Comment: Thank you very much.
I haven't figured out the cause in a long time.
Thank you.